# How to download audio in Progressive Web App to listen in offline mode

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I need develop a PWA to play and download podcasts to listen in online/offline mode too. The browser cache mobile is very small to do it. Are there any possible to download files and then get it to listen it in my PWA?
I need some ideas how to do it, do you have one? thank you.

Comment: Well, based on this [thread](http://softwareas.com/progressive-web-apps-have-leapfrogged-the-native-install-model-but-challenges-remain/), in the Progressive Web App there are still many basic functions that aren’t yet possible on the web. One of these is a full-fledged offline podcast app because of SSL and cross-domain restrictions. Another things that are not yet available are the Bluetooth, USB, and background audio. But, these APIs are all being worked on.